# React router show a page but don't add it to history

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have an app that does payment.  I want to show a processing page after the user clicks the "pay" button, and then render the payment result after the payment call has finished.

If the user clicks the back button while on the payment result page, they should go back to the payment page.

The problem is if I just push the processing page into the browser history, when the user clicks the back button, they're taken back to the processing page.

I also tried `replace(processingPage)`, but the result isn't what I want: it replaces the `/payment` in the browser with `/processing`.  What I need is not having `/processing` in the browser history.

Is there any way to achieve this behavior with React?

**Update 1**

This is not my code.

An alternative is to render a processing-component on top of the payment page, but that would require lots of code changes.

I just wonder if it's possible to do the above with React router.

Comment: Why do you need a route to do processing?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing `replace(paymentComplete)` from the processing page.

Alternatively put the processing screen in a modal and don't make it a route at all.